# Implementing atypical underline style

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need a special underline style for a rich textbox. The line/underline can have a different color than the text above it. The line should also have a shape that I haven't seen anywhere else.

Is it possible to implement this by leveraging some functionality, ideally inheriting from a rich text control?

I'm not sure how this can be done relatively easily so any hint is much appreciated. The only way I can think of is to implement it completely from scratch. E.g., using Graphics.DrawString, etc. Which would be awful lot of work.

I've also checked third-party controls like DevExpress, Telerik, Infragistics, ComponentOne, etc. But none of them seem to support this.

Comment: Have you tried using [`TextDecoration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.textdecoration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instances, which can be added to any [`Inline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.inline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the [`TextDecorations` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.inline.textdecorations%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), on your text? You may be able to influence the shape according to your wishes by supplying a custom pen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper This should be the answer here.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper - this is a very good idea ! I'll try that. Feel free to write it as an answer ... .

Answer (score 1):

*The [WPF `RichTextBox` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) serves for editing [`FlowDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instances, whose content is defined with the types from the [`System.Windows.Documents` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents(v=vs.110).aspx).*

Every `Inline` has a [`TextDecorations` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.inline.textdecorations%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It is a list of additional decorations (generally, in the form of lines) that are added to the text of the inline. Each of them is an instance of the [`TextDecoration` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.textdecoration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Each `TextDecoration` gets [its individual `Pen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.textdecoration.pen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so the colour is independent from the text color. The following example creates a text comprising green letters, a purple underline and an orange overline:

```
<Run Foreground="Green" Text="Hello, World!" FontSize="36">
    <Run.TextDecorations>
        <TextDecoration Location="Underline">
            <TextDecoration.Pen>
                <Pen Brush="Purple"/>
            </TextDecoration.Pen>
        </TextDecoration>
        <TextDecoration Location="OverLine">
            <TextDecoration.Pen>
                <Pen Brush="Orange"/>
            </TextDecoration.Pen>
        </TextDecoration>
    </Run.TextDecorations>
</Run>
```

Once you're there, you can supply a brush that does not completely fill the area, but rather draws shapes, such as a [`VisualBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), to create any pattern you want.